# What is the correct syntax for my datatables problem?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I have a data table which is loaded within a script like so:

```
<script>
        function table() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'tables/winnertable-all.php',
                type: 'get',
                data: { name: '<?php echo $name ?>', Type: '<?php echo $Type ?>'  },
                success: function(response){
                    $('.winnertable').html(response);
                    $('#newtable').DataTable();
                }
            });
        }
                                table();
        setInterval(table, 3600000);

                                table();
        setInterval(table, 3600000);
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#newtable').DataTable();
} );
    </script>
```

I would like to add default ordering to the first column, i have found this code on the data tables website as an example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "order": [[ 3, "desc" ]]
    } );
} );
```

I would like to implement this in my code, however i cannot get the table to load after adding the line.
I have tried:

```
<script>
        function table() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'tables/winnertable-all.php',
                type: 'get',
                data: { name: '<?php echo $name ?>', Type: '<?php echo $Type ?>'  },
                success: function(response){
                    $('.winnertable').html(response);
                    $('#newtable').DataTable();
                    "order": [[ 1, "desc" ]];

                }
            });
        }
                                table();
        setInterval(table, 3600000);

                                table();
        setInterval(table, 3600000);
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#newtable').DataTable();
    "order": [[ 1, "desc" ]];
} );
    </script>
```

I know their is a problem with my syntax implementation however i have tried various different things and cannot get it to work.

Comment: Your code does not match the sample. The sample has an object inside parentheses -- `DataTable( { "order": [[ 3, "desc" ]] } );` Your 'order' line is not even in the parentheses. Besides that, I can't tell if there is any data, but the ordering should be ok with that fix. Also work on formatting your code; it's a little hard to tell what's going on; 2 lines are repeated for some reason.

Comment: Can you share any errors that you're seeing in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, If you want to reinitialise a DataTable in order to change its basic settings, you need to use the [`destroy`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/destroy) flag.

However, in your case I would just add the desired `order`-settings to defaults

```js
$.extend( true, $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
  order: [[ 3, "desc" ]]
})
```

If you do that upfront, on pageload, all tables will have `order: [[ 3, "desc" ]]` as default. If you for some reason not want to alter the defaults, you can simply take advantage of the API, that surprise surprise have an [`order`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/order()) method

```js
var table = $('#newtable').DataTable()
table.order( [[ 3, "desc" ]] ).draw()
```